# Excel Function returning array

Tags: microsoft-excel, array, udf

I want a UDF that accepts a parameter and returns an array.

Here is my function:

```
Function UnitSales(ToAdd As Long) As Long()
     UnitSales = Array(1 + ToAdd, 2 + ToAdd, 3 + ToAdd)
End Function
```

I am trying to use the array by selecting 3 cells and typing =unitsales(3) then pressing Ctrl-Shift-Enter

All I get is 3 cells that say #VALUE!
I am expecting 3 cells to contain  4,5,6

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the `Long()` to `Variant()`

Comment: When I make that change I now get  =unitsales(3) in all three cells.

Comment: Make sure your cells are not set as `Text`

Comment: This is a fresh empty sheet so all cells are at their default.  I did try highlighting those cells and formatting them as numbers before putting in the formula but it did not help.

Comment: As you can see it works for me below.  Not sure what is up with yours, unless you have it set to show the formula.

Comment: Try hitting Ctrl-~ or F9

Comment: F9 did nothing,  Ctrl~ turned them all to FALSE.  Now I didn't use shift, so it was technically Ctrl `

Comment: OK, I didn't know about Ctrl tilde and yes it seems I must have accidentally pressed it at some point.  So now when I am not viewing formulas the cells say FALSE

Comment: Without seeing your sheet, I am at a lost.  Try opening a new workbook put the code I have in my answer in a new module highlight three cells across, put the formula in the formula bar and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: OK, I figured something out.  A blank sheet I didn't recognize called "Macro1" had appeared in my workbook.  I was using that sheet by mistake.  When I switched to the correct "Sheet1" I thought I was using, it now works.  Don't know what that's all about but I'm moving on.  And you were right, I needed Variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `Long()` to `Variant()`

```
Function UnitSales(ToAdd As Long) As Variant()
     UnitSales = Array(1 + ToAdd, 2 + ToAdd, 3 + ToAdd)
End Function
```

[image]